# Master Page in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

Can any one tell me what is difference between **Master page** and **Master Pages** in ASP.Net. Is both are same or different. Please help me. I have only few ideas here. Please.......

Comment: The same as between *orange* and *oranges*

Comment: No dear some one told be both are different. Please.....

Comment: Why don't you ask *someone* what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

Former is singular, latter is plural. Otherwise -- no difference whatsoever.

Comment: I know. But one of the interview is forcing the word Master pages not master page. He told me two three times that i am asking about master pages not master page. so that's why i am asking .......please

Comment: @galvin - is that the exact question the interviewer asked you? are you sure he wasnt just correcting grammer!?

Answer (score 1):

**No difference, they are the same thing.**

Different = No
Same = Yes

But master pages can be used in an inheritence based hierarchy.

Therefore TwoColumnMaster can inherit from MainMaster thus creating an application with master pages.

Comment: what i am asking Master page and Master pages both are same or different. I want answer in Only one word. Either Yes OR NO please.......

Answer (score 0):

Either the interviewer was fooling around with you or may be he/she read this particular line on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx#HowMasterPagesWork):

> Master pages actually consist of two
>   pieces, the master page itself and one
>   or more content pages.

In one word: YES: They are same but one can generate several definitions as MSDN has one above to confuse people.